# Error C3374: can't take address of 'ProjectName::on_mouse' unless creating delegate instance

Tags: visual-c++, image-processing, opencv

I am working on openCV camShift color detection algorithm. When I am trying to call 
`cvSetMouseCallback( "CamShiftDemo",&ProjectName::on_mouse,0);` function within the main method this gives me above mentiond C3374 Error in VC++.

this is the on_mouse function that I am using

```
static void on_mouse( int event, int x, int y, int flags,void* param )
{
    //function implementation 
}
```

I can't figure out what is the exact problem here.some forums say that, this is because of managed and unmanaged C++ codes. Can any one help me to get rid of this problem? Please share me a sample code to sort out this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assign it to appropriate delegate, rather than directly assigning it to some function-pointer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5408cs95(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: HI Ajay i can't understand MyDel ^ StaticDelInst = gcnew MyDel(a, &A::func1); this part of the code your have shared from MSDN can you please explain it to me.

Comment: I am not aware of OpenCV as such, so I cannot comment on what/where the error is occurring.